# Помогите с регулярным выражением для даты

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой текст:

> 14 сент. 2010 г. — I just finnished cleaing the dust off these clay pebbles. What's the best way to go about Cleaning and PH neutralizing them?

> 4 июл. 2021 г. — How to wash your balls (clay pebbles) POST grow mess & clean up. I've two Wilma systems running, 8 x 11liter pots absolutely filled with clay ...

Нужно вырезать даты с тире, то есть:

`14 сент. 2010 г. —`

`4 июл. 2021 г. —`

составил такое регулярное выражение:

```
preg_replace('/[0-9]{1,2}\s{1}/iU', '', $input_lines);
```

с числами справляется, но когда дальше подставляю, чтобы убрать *сент.* и *июл.*:

```
[0-9]{1,2}\s{1}[а-я]{3,4}
```

Ничего не получается.
Можете подсказать как правильно составить?

UPD. После обсуждения в комментариях получилось так:

```
preg_replace('/[0-9]{1,2}\s[а-я].+?\—\s/iU', '', $input_lines)
```

Comment: А зачем тут регулярное выражение если вы по тире можете определять границу?

Comment: Идея хорошая. Только сейчас пробую варианты на https://www.phpliveregex.com/#tab-preg-replace и что-то ничего не срабатывает. Можете подсказать как составить?

Comment: вроде бы разобрался:
`preg_replace('/.+?\.\s\—\s/iU', '', $input_lines);`

Comment: тогда так `preg_replace('/[0-9]{1,2}\s[а-я].+?\—\s/iU', '', $input_lines)`, ибо начало даты обозначить надо, если не делать этого - всё что после "переноса" и до даты будет так же попадать в условие

Comment: Да, спасибо! Это работает!